# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, reshape, attributeerror

I have about 100 samples with 35 features.I need to find best features from a set of features.the features are clinical and genomic details of patients with a particular type of cancer.I need to find what is the  best combination that give a high ACC.

this is my code:

```
import sys

import csv

import pandas as pd

from mlxtend.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector as SFS

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

with open("feature matrix", "r") as f:

for line in f:
        entries = line.split(',')
    for i in entries:
    if i.decode('utf-8')[0]==u'-':
        print 0-float(i.decode('utf-8')[1:])
            X = i.decode('utf-8')
y='survival'

X.shape 

y.shape

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(X, y, 
                                               stratify=y,
                                               test_size=0.3,
                                               random_state=1)


knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2)

sfs1 = SFS(estimator=knn,

       k_features=(3,35),

       forward=True, 

       floating=False, 

       scoring='accuracy',

       print_progress=False,

       cv=5)

 pipe = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), sfs1)

 pipe.fit(x_train,y_train)

 print('best combination (ACC: %.3f): %s\n' % 
 (sfs1.k_score_,sfs1.k_feature_idx_))
```

when i run the code,I get the following error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "sample_test.py", line 21, in <module>

X.shape 

AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I don't have enough experience yet to know what the next step is in troubleshooting.Is there a better way to code this?

Comment: You're getting the error because you've set `X = i.decode('utf-8')` which is a unicode object. I assume you're hoping to get X out as a matrix. In which case you may want to preallocate a matrix e.g. 
`import numpy as np`,
`np.zeros(N)` where N is the total number of elements in your feature matrix.
Then do something like:
`for index, entry in entries:`,
`....[stuff]`,
`X[index] = float(entry.decode('utf-8')[1:])`,
or whatever the correct entry is.
finally you'll need to reshape this array:
`X.reshap(n, m)`, where n and m are the number of rows and columns of your feature matrix

Comment: @ Jonathan Brooks-Thank You for the reply